# Error: Illegal Start of expression

Tags: java

I am constantly getting this error when trying to compile this program - I know that static variables are class-wide variables, and can't be put into non-static methods or variables. As I've seen in other questions by beginners of java(like me), it might 'right in your face' thing. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sims
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Class constructor
        System.out.println("Enter a last name");        
        static Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
            static String names1 = name.nextLine();//reading the input
        static String last_name = names1;
        intro();
    }

    public static void intro()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm an instance! " + last_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Local variables can't be `static`. Remove that keyword from `name`, `names1` and `last_name`.

Comment: `static` can be only used with class members, not with local variables. Let `intro` method accept string parameter and pass `last_name` as argument to it.

Comment: Also in your `intro` method, you're trying to access the local variable from the `main` method (once you remove the static declarations as suggested by other comments)

Comment: I like the Eclipse error message better: "*Illegal modifier for parameter name; only final is permitted*". Not entirely accurate either, since it's a local variable, not a parameter, but it's definitely more informative than JDK's "*illegal start of expression*" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` from all local variables in the main scope.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sims
{
    private String last_name;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Class constructor
        System.out.println("Enter a last name");        
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        String names1 = name.nextLine();//reading the input
        String last_name = names1;
        intro(last_name);
    }

    public static void intro(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("I'm an instance! " + name);
    }
}
```

Learn when to use `static`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html.

Comment: If you follow this answer, you still end up with compiler error "`last_name` cannot be resolved to a variable" in the `intro()` method.

Comment: Pass in last_name  in intro

Comment: Just learn how the language works. Relying on an IDE to tell you when to make API decisions is _**really, really bad.**_

Comment: I edited my answer, it still isnt perfect but i don´t feel like there are anymore edits i can make that will make OPs mind clearer here.